# How to tell if replacement occurred in Javascript replace function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a function that scans a series of strings and replaces them:

```
var nam = 'Here is a sample string 1/23';

var d   = new Date();
var mon = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

nam = nam.replace(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/,day+'/'+mon);
```

However, if no replacements are made (because the regex is not found in the string), I want to append `day+'/'+mon` to the end of the string.

How can I see the number of regex matches?

Comment: The simplest solution (not the only one) would be to compare the initial and the replaced string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

You can check for a match first before performing the replacement, but replacing it means evaluating the regex a second time, which, depending on the regex, can be pretty expensive:

```
var re = /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/;

if (re.test(nam))
    nam = nam.replace(re, day+'/'+mon);
else
    nam += day+'/'+mon;
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments, you can replace the string and compare it with the initial string — you simply need to put it in a temporary variable, which costs almost nothing:

```
var temp = nam.replace(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/, day+'/'+mon);

if (temp == nam)
    nam += day+'/'+mon;
else
    nam = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test it first:

```
nam = /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/.test(nam) ? nam.replace(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/,day+'/'+mon) : nam + day+'/'+mon;
```

Comment: This seems a bit excessive having to run regex twice. I like Denys solution.

Comment: It seems you have your if and else flipped, no?

Comment: this looks a bit nasty, you could at least store the regular expression in some variable to avoid repetitions...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know, if it was replaced and not which part exactly:

```
temp_nam = nam.replace(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/,day+'/'+mon);
replaced = (temp_nam == nam) ? false : true;
--- more code ---
nam = temp_nam;
```

Just store the replaced string in a temporary variable and write it after the check back in the real variable.